# Query jsonb array column

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm not having any luck querying a `jsonb[]` column (attributes). I couldn't find anything in the Postgresql docs about arrays of jsonb

My data in the column is a bunch of objects in an array like this:

```sql
1 - [{ "trait_type": "color", "value": "blue" },{ "trait_type": "hair", "value": "short" }]
2 - [{ "trait_type": "color", "value": "red" },{ "trait_type": "hair", "value": "short" }]
3 - [{ "trait_type": "color", "value": "green" },{ "trait_type": "hair", "value": "long" }]
4 - [{ "trait_type": "color", "value": "blue" },{ "trait_type": "hair", "value": "med" }]
```

I tried this:
`SELECT * FROM public.items WHERE attributes @> '[{ "trait_type": "color", "value": "blue" }]';`

...but get error:
`Failed to run sql query: malformed array literal: "[{ "trait_type": "color", "value": "blue" }]"`

I also tried:
`SELECT * FROM public.items WHERE attributes @> ARRAY['{ "trait_type": "color", "value": "blue" }'];`

...but get error:
`Failed to run sql query: operator does not exist: jsonb[] @> text[]`

Comment: Do not use `jsonb[]`. Use `jsonb` and store an array value into it.

Comment: You "like this" data is not valid for jsonb[].  What is really stored in that column?